# How to check multiple rows of a checkbox on a DataGridView and set the value to a variable?

Tags: vba, vb.net

Please help me. I have a requirement to select data from the Employee table in an Oracle database and set the data to a DataGridView on a SearchForm. However, I am struggling with how to check multiple rows' checkboxes on DataGridView and set the values to a variable as a list. I have tried, but I can't seem to check them. How can I perform the Checked event on DataGridView?

```
Dim selectedEmployees As New List(Of String)
For Each selectedRow As DataGridViewRow In DGV_SEARCH.SelectedRows
selectedEmployees.Add(employeeNo)
selectedEmployees.Add(employeeName)
Next
Private Sub DGV_SEARCH_CellClick_1(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_SEARCH.CellClick
If DGV_SEARCH.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(DGV_SEARCH.Columns(DGV_SELECTED.Name).Index) Then
                If Convert.ToInt32(DGV_SEARCH.CurrentRow.Cells(DGV_SELECTED.Name).Value) = 0 Then
                    DGV_SEARCH.CurrentRow.Cells(DGV_SELECTED.Name).Value = 1
                Else
                    DGV_SEARCH.CurrentRow.Cells(DGV_SELECTED.Name).Value = 0
                End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not really too sure exactly what you're trying to achieve exactly.  Guessing you want to set the value of the checkbox on all rows.  If so, generally (assuming you've got this datagridview bound) you are better off implementing this logic on the data collection than directly on the DGV

Comment: @hursey I  want to set the value of the checkbox on some rows not all rows

Comment: That really doesn't change anything.  You can still do logic to conditionally update the fields in the bound data source.  In my mind you're almost always better than not to do this type of thing in the data and leave the UI to do what it does best which is user interaction

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pull the data - whatever query or sql you like.

Then, add a check box column to that data pull, and shove the results into a data gridview.

So, say this code to load:

```
Private Sub SelectRows_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
        FROM tblHotelsA
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRst(strSQL)
    Dim MycheckCol As New DataColumn("Select", GetType(Boolean))
    MycheckCol.DefaultValue = False
    rstData.Columns.Add(MycheckCol)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = rstData


End Sub
```

And then a button below the grid, and it can pick up the selected rows like this:

```
    Dim strSelList As String = ""

    For Each MyRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        If MyRow.Cells(6).Value = True Then
            If strSelList <> "" Then strSelList &= ","

            strSelList &= MyRow.Cells(0).Value

        End If

    Next

    TextBox1.Text = "Row PK values selected = " & strSelList
```

the results look like this:

[image]

so, just pick up a "list" of pk row id's as per above.